# How to execute a set of commands after closing the popup window

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button in an page when i click on it, it will execute a set of commands and then open a popup page.

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
/*set of commands*/
 string arry = String.Join(",", ((string[])a1.ToArray(typeof(String))));
                        string url = "AreaGridValue.aspx?list="+ arry;
                        string s = "window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=300,height=100,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');";
                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);
}
```

Now i want to execute more set of codes after closing the popup window how do i do that without loosing the values in the parent page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may name the opened popup like:

```
var popup = window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=300,height=100,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');
```

and using a `setInterval()` check if the window is closed and run other codes:

```
var int = setInterval(function(){ if(popup.closed === true) { clearInterval(int); /*write your code here*/} } ,50);
```

I omitted the part that you put these code in a c# string and wrote the javascript part as actually nothing new in the c# part.

So finally it will be something like this:

```
string url = "AreaGridValue.aspx?list="+ arry;
string s = "var popup = window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=300,height=100,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');";
s += "var int = setInterval(function(){ if(popup.closed === true) { clearInterval(int); alert('popup closed');} } ,50);";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);
```

So when the popup windows is closed, the function in the `setInterval` would be executed, and in the above example would show an alert saying "popup is closed".

Comment: Hi @ashkan thanks for the quick response. But the parent window should execute a set of commands and not the child window

Comment: @ashish well this code goes to the parent window, and parent windows executes it, the `popup` is defined in parent window, and the `setIterval()` that checks if the `popup` is closed is also in the parent window, and execute when the popup is closed.

Comment: Could you describe in detail how this javascript function is used and how it is closed as you can see my popup window is nothing but an aspx page. So could you help with the full code on how to do this.

Comment: Hi i tried this but i get an error Error: 'popup' is undefined then i changed popup to Error: 'popup_window' is undefined but still the same error message

Comment: @ashish opss, sorry when i wrote it forgot to add `var popup = ` to your code. please copy the code again.

Comment: Hi Ashkan thanks this worked. But say now i want to execute few C# codes how do i do that instead of showing the alert window that popup is closed? say if i want to add items into list or something how do i do that?

Comment: you can not execute c# codes client-side, however instead of the alert, you can write an ajax code there to call a page that executes the c# codes.

Comment: Hi Ashkan, Is it possible to call a method that is there in the parent class?

Comment: @ashish of course, but remember that the javascript function you are calling must be defined when you execute it

Comment: Yes but the method is something like  
public static string GetData()

        {

            return "This string is from Code behind";

        } which is want to call in the set interval could you help me with the code?

Comment: its a c# method, remember that your c# code is on server-side while when you get the html, javascript is in the client-side, so you have no access to run c# code in client-side. as i already said, you may want to call a page via ajax that runs the c# code you want